# CRM: <ThresholdDate> field from Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.SystemState.xml getting reset to some date in the past

Tags: .net, dll, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a .Net application and we are using CRM with it. We had a production release a couple of days back. After doing CRM rollout, we found that something went wrong and email router stopped processing incoming emails in CRM (which had never been a problem before the production release).

After getting help from Microsoft for the same, we got to know that:

While monitoring the Event logs, they found that Email Router was processing emails which were created in the year “2013”. They checked the `ThresholdDate` Value in the `Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.SystemState.xml` file and found that it was set to the year 2013. They modified the value to “2014-05-18”. After waiting for a while, Email Router started processing the recent emails and they could see those emails coming in to CRM.

Being more specific about this, we got to know from Microsoft that: 
Email Router has its own algorithm, based on which it creates a new `Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.SystemState.xml` file after a period of time, after making a backup of the existing `Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.SystemState.xml` file. The new `Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.SystemState.xml` created by Email Router contains the most recent threshold date. They were not sure why the Threshold date would be changed back to the year “2013”.

My Q is:
What are the possibilities because of which the date would have been updated? Is it because of some old plugin which we pushed to Prod?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Not sure but you can give this a try:**

1) Stop Email Router service after upgrade

2) Change log on account for Email Router service

3) Delete the file C:\Program Files\Microsoft CRM Email\Service\Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.SystemState.xml

4) Start Email Router service

This will allow Email Router to use the contents of the backup system state file of CRM 4.0 that was created during upgrade. It will then re-populate the StateXML values and thereby continuing to process the mails where it left off in CRM 4.0

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2491350

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even, I found this solution. But, I am actually interested in knowing the cause of the problem. I am trying to figure out why it happened. If I can get to know the reason, I can make sure that this issue does not arise during next prod release.